# ejs error saying "Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%="."

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

When I clicking on read more button it saying could not find symbol `<%=`

```html
<% posts.forEach(function(post){ %>  
  <div class="main-container card">
    <div class="innerContent">
      <p><i class="name"><%= post.email %></i></p>
      <h2><%= post.title %></h2>
      <div class="border1"></div>
        <p class="content"><%= post.content %></p>
        <a href="/posts/<%=post._id%>">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: Missing spaces around this `<a href="/posts/<%=post._id%>` perhaps?

Comment: not working brother

Comment: How does view-source look like, sister?

Comment: app.get("/dynamicPost", function(req, res){
    User.find({},function(err, posts){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            res.render("home", {
                posts:posts
            });
        }
    })
})

Comment: How does view-source of your HTML look like!??

Comment: Pls update the question